# How can I change the prefilled data-color attribute based on a classname?

Tags: html, jquery, css, attributes

I have this code:

```
<canvas data-color="40,97,245">
```

The problem? The color is already filled in and I want to make sure the data-color changes when there is a certain classname on canvas.

The problem is that I can't change the `color` of it. Background-color works, but text and line colors do not change. Is there a way to do this?

So, e.g.

```
<canvas class="changeToBlue" data-color="#BLUE COLOR HEX">
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things:

- Setting attributes, `data` or otherwise, is not the right way to set colors when drawing.
- The reason the CSS `background-color` property "works" is because the canvas element is transparent to start. Drawing color, whether for lines, texts, or shapes, is not styleable through CSS. The `color` property only affects DOM text, which canvas-drawn text is not.

Instead, you want to work with the 2d drawing context. To set the colors, get the drawing context then set the `fillStyle` or `strokeStyle` properties. See the MDN help page for more info on [strokes and colors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors).

Example of setting the style:

```
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
```

---

Full Snippet:

```js
function setBlues() {
  let canvases = document.querySelectorAll('canvas.changeToBlue');
  
  for (let canvas of canvases) {
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  }
}

function draw() {
  let canvases = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');

  for (let canvas of canvases) {
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillText('Filled', 10, 50);
    ctx.strokeText('Stroked', 10, 30);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(75, 50);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 75);
    ctx.lineTo(100, 25);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

setBlues();
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="changeToBlue" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3" class="changeToBlue" width="150" height="150" style="background-color:gold"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using jquery.

```
$(".changeToBlue").attr("data-color","#000000");
```